# Remove social media sharing buttons on a download page

Tags: pages

I have a couple of social media sharing plugsin installed, but wonder if there is any way of removing them from one specific page that I have as a download page for a product?

Comment: Please elaborate which specific plugins (including a link to them) you are using, when asking such questions. It is not answerable in current form.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the plugins. Some sharing plugins will allow you to set a per-page setting on whether to show or hide the sharing buttons. Jetpack's Sharing module is one of them: http://jetpack.me/support/sharing/